# How to reduce audio noise in a WebRTC app

Tags: node.js, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I'm working on video chatting application using peer to peer WebRTC approach where video looks fine but audio is having some extra noise occurring.

Here is my code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true},function(stream){},function(error){});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "noise" exactly? Does this happen on all browsers? Does it sound worse than other common WebRTC sites you've tried as a user?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of noise are we talking about?
Is it ambient noise (from surrounding)? in which case you may want to get a better microphone.
Is your audio clear and remote audio is noisy? You will need to check conditions over there too.

Or, are we talking about noise when audio is passed through webRTC?
You may want to pass audio through browser defined filters. See firefox examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode).
Note that it will be browser dependent. You may find similar example for Chrome etc.

Or you will need to pass the audio-stream through external filters that can fix the audio quality both at transmitting and receiving end.